# extJs Alert Help

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

```
var encClinic = new Ext.chart.StackedBarChart({
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        reader:encReader,
        url:data.jsonUrl,
        baseParams:{
            cmd:'OHMjson.Graph',
            graphName:'ENC',
            graphType:'Clinics'
        }
    }),
    yField: 'CLINIC',
    xAxis: new Ext.chart.NumericAxis({
        stackingEnabled: true,
        title: text.occurrences
    })
});
```

1. I am displaying some values here, i need to debug by displaying an alert here whether the data retrieved are correct or not.
2. Can anyone explain me the code too.

Comment: Only you know if the data is correct or not? You can add an exception listener to the store to capture errors there, if you want to capture issues with data values I'd add a load listener and process the records there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code for what Lloyd is talking about.  I have added an exception listener and a load listener for you.  Since I don't have the data, the particulars of what is inside of records.data will probably need some tweaking to get it to work right for you.

```
var encClinic = new Ext.chart.StackedBarChart({
store: new Ext.data.Store({
    reader:encReader,
    url:data.jsonUrl,
    baseParams:{
        cmd:'OHMjson.Graph',
        graphName:'ENC',
        graphType:'Clinics'
    },
    listeners : {
          exception : function(misc) {
                 //Exception Handling Here
                 //Handle your  load failures here
          },
          load      : function(this, records, opts) {
                //evaluate to see if your data is "correct"
                alert(records.data.toString());
          }

}),
yField: 'CLINIC',
xAxis: new Ext.chart.NumericAxis({
    stackingEnabled: true,
    title: text.occurrences
})
```

});

Comment: I added comments... Is commented code not sufficient?  I think the comments are self sufficient